# I'm trying to make login-logout page,coding is completed but when i'm log in it's can't go to log out page

Tags: php

This is my coding of form and database connectivity.I don't know what is wrong in my coding.

```
try 
 {         
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$servername};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);     

$query="SELECT username, password FROM session WHERE username='$name' and password='$password'";    

$sql = $db->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();

 $row = $sql->fetch();

 echo $row;
 if($row != NULL){

     header('location:next.php');
     }
}
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{         
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
```

Comment: Please try to explain your problem a bit better. Do you have problems with redirecting? What is next.php doing? Where is your logout-page? Show a bit more of your codes.

Comment: Are you using the same $password variable to connect to database and to authenticate the user? I guess you may want to use different variables for it.